# String comparisons not returning correctly?

Tags: java, string, variables

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Poop {
  public static void main (String args[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String Gender;
    System.out.println("Are you a boy or a girl?");
    Gender = input.nextLine();

    if(Gender == "boy"){
      System.out.println("You are a boy.");
    }
    if(Gender == "girl"){
      System.out.println("You are a girl.");
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to know why this program isn't working. In Eclipse it says there is no errors but when i run it and type in boy or girl nothing happens and I don't see why.

Also please no making fun of the program I am testing myself on string variables.

Comment: My best guess is that a modern compiler finds your characterisation of boys and girls too sexist to accept and simply ignores your code.

Comment: Yeah. That and the string compares. Cuz I'm cute *and* cool. Except for the cute and cool parts.

Comment: Every time someone compares `String`s with `==` a developer cries...

Answer (score 9):

If you are comparing Strings, don't use `==`, but use `equals()`:

```
if(Gender.equals( "boy" ) ){
  System.out.println("You are cool.");
}
if(Gender.equals( "girl" ) ){
  System.out.println("You are cute.");
}
```

In Java `==` compares object identities and not contents! So in your case your compare the object, you read in, with two others objects. This will always fail.

On the other hand `equals()` compares the contents of both objects and thus will succeed here.

Comment: +1 for explaining why == isn't the right choice.

Comment: Thanks I know it was simple but I'm new to java. Also thanks for the quick response.

Comment: And another +1 for explaining this for the zillionst time...

Answer (score 1):

Use `.equals()` for string comparision not `==`

I have just answered an answer: exactly same problem
Use equals method for string comparision.

`==` will not compare string object's string value it just checks for reference equality.

In this respect if you compare two string objects with same value they are not equal by `==` operator

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Poop {
   public static void main (String args[]){
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      String Gender;
      System.out.println("Are you a boy or a girl?");
      Gender = input.nextLine();

      if(Gender.equals("boy")){
         System.out.println("You are cool.");
      }
      if(Gender.equals("girl")){
         System.out.println("You are cute.");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I know it was simple but I'm new to java. Also thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a duplicate of this answer:
[What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion)

Use `equals` instead of `==` in java for stirng comparison

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Poop {
public static void main (String args[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String Gender;
    System.out.println("Are you a boy or a girl?");
    Gender = input.nextLine();

    if(Gender.equals("boy")){
        System.out.println("You are cool.");
}
if(Gender.equals("girl")){
    System.out.println("You are cute.");
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks I know it was simple but I'm new to java. Also thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized multiple same answers. Reason is same, use `.equals` instead of `==`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Poop {
public static void main (String args[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String Gender;
    System.out.println("Are you a boy or a girl?");
    Gender = input.nextLine();

    if(Gender.equals("boy")){
        System.out.println("You are cool.");


}
if(Gender.equals("girl")){


    System.out.println("You are cute.");
}

}}
```

Comment: Thanks I know it was simple but I'm new to java. Also thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .equals for string comparison.

```
if(Gender.equals("boy"))
```

Or you could intern the input like so, and then use ==

```
Gender = input.nextLine().intern();
if(Gender=="boy")
```

Interesting program though :D

Comment: Thanks I know it was simple but I'm new to java. Also thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting in on this...

`==` tests if the two String objects are the *same* object.
`.equals()` tests if the two Strings have the same "value"

Change your tests to `if(Gender.equals("boy"))` etc.

Java ain't javasript.

Comment: Thanks I know it was simple but I'm new to java. Also thanks for the quick response.